# how to get RGB value from an image by touching or moving on a screen in Xamarin or C#

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

how to get RGB value from an image by touching or moving on a screen in Xamarin or C#.

what I mean is I would like to get RGB value form an image just pixel that I'm touching and when I moving my finger or touch another pixel I will get the new RGB value.
Please help me. How can I do that?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

1. Custom image renderer for each platform that implements reading screen coordinates on OnTouch event.
2. Skiasharp library.

then you can get color with this pseudo code:

```
    private SKColor GetPixelColor(SKPoint point, SKBitmap bitmap)
    {
        SKColor color;
        color = bitmap.GetPixel((int)point.X, (int)point.Y);
        return color;
    }
```

SKColor lets you get:

```
var red = color.Red;
var green = color.Green;
var blue = color.Blue;
```